# Use pointer notation to print a character array

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I know that for a given integer array, a pointer to that integer array, I can access the integer array using something like this:

```
int main(){

  int x[4] = {0,1,2,3};
  int *ptr;

  ptr = x;

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%d", *(ptr+i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now say I have a character array instead, doing the same thing doesnt work.

```
int main(){

  char x[4] = "Haha"; 
  char *ptr;

  ptr = x;

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%s", *(ptr+i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Apparently `*(ptr+i)` in the first code increments the pointer to the integer 4 bytes each time.  It doesnt work for the second code. How do I use the same notation for character array? I think the idea is to increment one char each time.

Comment: %s is for an array of chars (null terminated string), %c is for a single character.    printf("%c", *(ptr+i));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print each letter after a loop so you should correct your source code:
`printf("%s", *(ptr+i));` into `printf("%c", *(ptr+i));`
I think you should change `char x[4] = "Haha";` into `char x[5] = "Haha";` because, maybe in this case it doesn't cause any errors but sometimes, you will get overflown, be careful!